# High resolution background image gives performance issues in Android

Tags: android, xml, imageview, image-resizing, picasso

I want to have a background image that scales to fit any screen size in Android. The image is static and doesn't need to scroll. I made the image at 4K resolution to cover what is a likely resolution to exist on tablets in the next 2-3 years (2560 x 1600 already exist). The image is a JPG with a 137KB file size. Similar resolution images seem to work fine in Android web browsers. Why am I getting a lot of slow down in Android (on Samsung Galaxy S3, which should have plenty of CPU/RAM to handle an image like this)? I don't feel like I am doing anything out of the ordinary.

This loads the image in the XML layout. The image is currently stored in drawable-nodpi.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Making different size images for each category of screen resolution is difficult as I cannot find information on what the current maximum resolution for a device in each category is only a minimum.

I want to use the same background image again and again between a variety of fragments. Is there a way to have the image resized once to the width of the screen (preferably asynchronously) and then load that resized image each time? Could this be done with Picasso?

*Please don't give answers like "of course larger images result in performance issues" or link me to Google's Supporting Different Densities. This is a real issue that is going to become more of an issue as screen resolutions continue to increase. I am amazed that handling and resizing large images is not already optimised in the ImageView class, which makes me think I am doing something wrong.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that what you are trying to do is not relying on the SDK. By having one image and having to change the image on runtime, you are causing more work to be done on the UI thread in onDraw().

Of course you would be able to create a Bitmap for a specific size, but why do such complicated work when you can rely on the SDK?

Currently there are a bunch of different folders that you can use in order to get what you are looking for, and then in the future you can get a 4k image put into a specific folder. Things like this might work:

drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xlarge-xhdpi - May not be specific enough for what you are trying to accomplish
drawable-sw600dp - This allows you to specify a folder for an image where the screen width is greater than 600dp. This qualifier will probably be helpful for your case, in the future where you will be using 4k images.

Comment: Different size images based on screen width sounds like a good solution. I will try it out. I agree that resizing the image is additional work but to my mind it is negligible additional work. I can take the same image and resize the window up and down extremely rapidly on my old laptop without any noticeable delay in the image being perfectly rendered. The laptop has similar CPU/RAM to the Android phone I am using but laptop the resize takes I would guess under 50ms but on the Android device it takes around 3 seconds.

Comment: @TTransmit Exactly, it works just fine in the browser on the same device. Clearly there is something very wrong with the native drawable or ImageView implementation that causes this extreme inefficiency when dealing with large images.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that android uses `Bitmap` to render images to canvas. It is like BMP image format for me. So, you have no gain from JPG format, cuz all information lost from jpg conversion are lost forever and you will end up will fullsize bitmap anyway. The problem with big resolution is that, you have to address few bytes for every pixel, no conversion applied! In particular, smaller devices have lower memory class as bigger ones. So, you have to handle the image resolution based on device screen size and memory class.

You can properly convert your background bitmap at runtime with these helper functions:

```
public void getScreenSizePixels(Resources resources, int widthHeightInPixels[/*2*/])
    {
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        double screenWidthInPixels = (double)config.screenWidthDp * dm.density;
        double screenHeightInPixels = screenWidthInPixels * dm.heightPixels / dm.widthPixels;
        widthHeightInPixels[0] = (int)(screenWidthInPixels + .5);
        widthHeightInPixels[1] = (int)(screenHeightInPixels + .5);
    }
```

--

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] imageAsBytes, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        imageAsBytes,
        0,
        imageAsBytes.length,
        opt);
    int width = opt.outWidth;
    int height = opt.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (reqWidth < (width / scale) || reqHeight < (height / scale)) {
      scale++;
    }
    //bitmap.recycle();
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    opt.inSampleSize = scale;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        imageAsBytes,
        0,
        imageAsBytes.length,
        opt);
    return bitmap;
  }
```